# Referencing an enum in an Angular component before using it

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I have the following component:

```js
@Component({
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  // Must reference the enum to be able to use types later
  enumModalContentType = EnumModalContentType;
  // Changes according to button clicks to point to the right component to show in modal
  modalContentType: EnumModalContentType;
}
```

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="modalContentType = enumModalContentType.EnumValue" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
 Launch demo modal
</button>

<app-modal [contentType]="modalContentType"></app-modal>
```

Which works perfectly well. My question is: why is it that we're obliged to reference EnumModalContentType in order to be able to use it in the HTML later? Why can't we just use it as a type directly?

Comment: Because templates do not have the same scoping mechanism as the classes they are bound to. Specifically, the enum is available to the module defining the component via lexical scoping. A template's scope is entirely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all comes down to scope.  It is the same reason why if you are building AOT, you can't have `private` variables used in your templates.  There must be a local public variable in the same scope as your template.  At build time, everything is logically separated and scoped, and without a local variable there is nothing for the template to bind to.

Comment: Do you have a reference for "if you are building AOT, you can't have private variables used in your templates" ? I did not know that was a thing. In my experience when I build with AOT via angular cli this has never been an issue/?

Comment: That is from personal experience, during compilation it would say 'such and such a variable doesn't exist' and that was because it was marked private.  If a variable isn't marked with `private`, it is public by default.

Comment: That is very interesting, I honestly have never encountered that, and I am actually rather anal about explicitly defining private and public declarations as well. This is good information though incase I ever receive that error!

Comment: And to be honest, that was an error I encountered early on and I've been strict about it since.  It is certainly possible that whatever caused that has changed.

Comment: Or potentially angular cli mitigates the issue when building with `--prod` which is AOT. Not sure would have to look it up. I do agree with your answer though +1.

Comment: Here is an interesting link about the AOT/private variable issue with CLI:  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14739   Private properties would cause it to fail, then certain recent versions would not fail, but the expected behavior is to fail.

Comment: You've come through with the goods there - thank you for that insight! Maybe I have been playing in a minefield unknowingly.. I pray my colleagues are running the same cli version as I am!....

Comment: Fair enough. Is there a more "elegant" way to do this? Like to use `typeof` or constants or something else?

Comment: You could use a constant, but that would still be a variable the template still has to access through the component.  Whether the variable sits in that component or a shared service injected into that component doesn't really matter.  I can't think of how that could be accomplished without a property sitting somewhere the template has access to.

Comment: @TylerJennings So this just bit me pretty hard - went to build with an updated ng-cli and boom 100's of errors - the pain.... Fortunately we had this conversation and I know exactly how to ammend this.